# SQL 2005/2008 and sp_add_jobstep fails

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a job that is being created by a non-sysadmin user. This job fails because the `@database_user_name` setting with the error `"Only a sysadmin can specify '@database_user_name' parameter"`

If I read BOL this would be ignored in SQL 2008 R2 which I have confirmed I am running with `@@version`.

Any thoughts?

```
EXECUTE @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @JobID, @step_id = 1, 
@step_name = N'Delete From TmpEmployee', 
@command = N'Delete From TmpEmployee', 
@database_name = @Database, @server = N'', 
@database_user_name = N'',
@subsystem = N'TSQL', @cmdexec_success_code = 0, @flags = 0, @retry_attempts = 0, 
@retry_interval = 1, @output_file_name = N'', @on_success_step_id = 2, 
@on_success_action = 4, @on_fail_step_id = 0, @on_fail_action = 2
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `@database_user_name = N''` parameter from the statement.  When created, the job owner will be the login that ran the statement.

You can then run `sp_update_job @owner_login_name='MyLogin'` to change the ownership.  This can be run by a member of `sysadmin` someone in either the `SQLAgentUserRole`, `SQLAgentReaderRole`, or `SQLAgentOperatorRole` in `msdb`.

Alternatively, add the user to one of the above msdb roles.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I have already done this for a test. The issue is the commands belong to a vendor and that will require a change request and we know sometimes this takes time.

Comment: Also, is BOL wrong that SQL 2008 R2 will ignore this? I was hoping sql 2008 R2 would be my fix.